# SSIS DT_DBDateTimeStamp to DD/MM/YYYY without script task (derived column)

Tags: ssis, derived-column

I'm trying to construct an SSIS package where one of the columns is a DT_DBDataTimeStamp format.

My problems is that I have to convert this to a DD/MM/YYYY format and I can't use a C# script.

I'm trying to use a derived column by having difficulty in getting the correct format.

I've tried Convert(varchar, Date_Column, 103) - doesn't work.
I've tried DAY(Date_Column) + MONTH(Date_Column) + YEAR(Date_Column) - doesn't work.

Anybody know how I can do this?

Comment: Please post the way you attempted to use DAY()+MONTH()+YEAR().   And the exact error message you got.  It does work if you do it correctly.

Comment: Sorry, I doesn't - I've tried a number of times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would need to be varchar if you want this (actually, I will use nvarchar for simplicity):

```
right("0" + (DT_WSTR,2) day(Date_Column), 2) + "/" +
right("0" + (DT_WSTR,2) month(Date_Column) , 2) + "/" +
(DT_WSTR,4)year(Date_Column)
```

Comment: I can't get this to work -  thanks for your input though, much appriciated

Comment: I forgot to cast year

Comment: Thanks, after playing around this worked - much appreciated

Comment: Please don't forget to mark the answer as it will stop people from coming to answer your question.